# Trying to understand the Drupal 7 computed fields module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-computed-field

I just installed the computed fields module and I'm a little lost as to how to use it. I have 2 fields in my content type: `field_shortdesc` and `field_audio_description`.

If `field_shortdesc` is blank I need to display `field_audio_description` and vice-versa.

What code do I need to place into the computed code and display code areas? Seems like I can't get even the simplest code to work.

For example if I put `$entity_field[0]['value'] = "test";` in the computed area and then put `print $entity_field[0]['value'];` in the display code area nothing gets printed out. Obviously I'm doing something completely wrong.

Comment: Please also note, that the changes in PHP code are visible after editing and saving content item, not just refreshing the content. It took me some time before I realized that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the help text in the Display Code section states:

> This code should assign a string to the `$display_output` variable,
>   which will be printed when the field is displayed.

Instead of `print $entity_field[0]['value']` try `$display_output = $entity_field[0]['value']`

Comment: Tried that and I still get nothing returned. :(

Comment: @DustinMcGrew - Notice also that the help text states: _Note: this code has no effect if you use the "Raw computed value" display formatter._ Check your display settings to make sure it's not set as such.

Comment: I'm assuming this is set in the View? Right now I have the formatter set to Plain Text. Right now for my computed code I have `$entity_field[0]['value'] = $node->field_shortdesc[0]['value'];` and the display code is `$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];`  

This does not put any value into my view.

Comment: @DustinMcGrew Try `$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_shortdesc[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` as your computed code. Note I have set the language to none and you may have to adjust accordingly for your site. If that doesn't work, try the simpler version of `$entity_field[0]['value'] = "test";` that you had in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think computed fields module is not the right solutin for your requirement.

In my opinion using Ajax state system is the best choice.

http://colorado2010.camps.drupal.org/drupalcampcolorado.org/sessions/dynamic-forms-drupal-7-ajax-and-states.html

http://drupal.org/node/752056

Comment: This is not for the node form. This is for simply displaying the field values on the front-end. I just need to programmatically determine if one field has no value. If it has no value then display the other field and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about displaying the values in a view that uses fields, rather than viewing the node, there's an easier way to do this through the view settings, without adding another field.

**If you only want to show one default value, even if both are present**:

- Add field 1 (the optional field) to the view but exclude from display
- Add field 2 (the default field) to the view and edit the "No results
  behavior" to show the value of field 1 when field 2 is empty.

**If you want to show both values if both are present, and you are using a table**:

- Add both fields to the view, but in table settings put the display of field 1 in the same column with field 2, using whatever separator is appropriate.  If one field or the other is empty, views appears to be smart enough not to output the separator.

**If not using a table, but want to show both values**:

- Add field 1 and exclude from display.
- Add field 2 and edit the "Rewrite Results" settings to show both.  Be sure that the "Hide
  rewriting if empty" box under "No results behavior" is not checked.